# xubuntu, wmctrl listing a single large display when I have two monitors

Tags: gnome, xfce, xubuntu, wmctrl

I currently have two monitors connected to my computer, the following:

```
[ON LEFT]    [ON RIGHT]
1920x1200     1600x900
```

When I run `wmctrol -d` I get the following output:

```
0  * DG: 1152x864  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,25 3520x1175  1
```

I also get a similar output of `3520x1200` when running:

```
xdpyinfo | grep 'dimension' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Similarly `xdpyinfo` outputs that my number of screens is `1`.

Both outputs suggest that my screen size is close to 3500x1200. However I have two screens, how can I get the dimensions of both monitors separately and then, how can I easily tell which monitor has the currently active window?

Or, how can I change my configuration so my system tells me I have two screens; because that may be the problem by itself.

Comment: Are you using the nVidia binary driver?

Comment: No I am not. I currently am using the integrated graphics card on my Sandy-Bridge CPU.